# Way to inherit schema from diffrent DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm working with multi-tenant application it's neccassary to understand context.

I have role db schema (let's call this sampleDB) which has his own DbContext. I'm using migration on this database. This database is example how should database for every client should looks like.
Each client has his own version of sampleDB and his data unique for him. I have defined ClientDbContext which is created based on his unique name whenever client need to access to his database. Problem occurs with schema update of his database. I don't want to this manually for every client because I can have plenty of them.

When ClientDbContext is created i'd like to run migrations which were applied for SampleDb (schemas of ClientDb and SampleDb has to be the same). I cannot do that manualy (Update-Database) because connection string for client db is know at runtime.
Migration history is not neccassary in ClientDbContext but I can't update his Db at runtime.
I have defined method wchi runs Migrations :

```
        public async Task StartMigrationAsync()
    {
        await this.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }
```

I can't define Migration folder for that method.

I have no idea how to resolve this issue without loosing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way a solved a problem:
Migration system is necessary for development time mostly so if sth goes wrong there won't be consequences (except time :P )

Each model which is used in application is packed with ClientModel:

```
public class ClientModel<TModel>{
    string dbName
    TModel Model
}
```

Then I just creating instance of db contextext base on provided dbName.
Migration are created based on our sampleClientDb which hold schema and is used as reference point to client dbs.
Migrations are run by reaching endpoint in our api which fire method .MigrateAsync().

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically running migrations is possible, but no encouraged. Instead, always create a script of the migration, check it (backup the target database etc.) and then apply the script.

As for the multi-tenant scenario, you could just keep a copy of the full migration script. When a new tenant is created, just run the SQL command to create a new database and then apply the script in the context/connection of the new database.